# jQuery library interfering with Javascript for navbar & filterable portfolio small issue - bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so I've spent the past 3 days trying to figure this out and Im so close! I actually went back and forth between a couple tutorials for the filterable portfolio and ended up using:

http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/jquery-quicksand-tutorial-filtering

Now Im having a couple of issues here.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VeaK9/

**Issue 1:** I have a .js file to make my navbar stay fixed to the top of the page after you scroll past the hero unit. Now this file works, but when I include the .js library required for my filterable portfolio neither the portfolio section works OR the navbar!

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And the code for the navbar is:

```
$(function () {
/*    $(".navbar-fixed-top").css({"top":$(".jumbotron").height()});

$(window).resize(function (e) {
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").css({"top":$(".jumbotron").height()});
});*/
$(document).on( 'scroll', function(){
    console.log('scroll top : ' + $(window).scrollTop());
    if($(window).scrollTop()>=$(".jumbotron").height())
    {
         $(".navbar").addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
    }

    if($(window).scrollTop()<$(".jumbotron").height())
    {
         $(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
    }
});
});
```

**Issue 2:** Now the second issue is the big one (something small for someone else out there lol) so of course in the tutorial I used for the portfolio, bootstrap was not used! And I didn't want to copy all of the css from the tutorial so I tried to make it work with bootstrap and I ran into this issue, there is an extra space on the left of the images and they actually overlap each other a little bit and pop out of the container!

Can anyone take a second and check this out? Please lol thank you guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your quicksand plugin was using a very old version of jQuery that was incompatible with the other one you were using. So we simple use the [Jquery Migrate Plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) and we are good to go.

So I removed the old version of jquery you were using with that plugin and added this at the end of your HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

Here is the fiddle with it working!

http://jsfiddle.net/hKvCN/

Answer to your **second** question

I'm not sure if I entirely understand the second question but here is a swing.

Try changing:

```
<div class="container portfolio">
```

to

```
<div class="container-fluid portfolio">
```

And let me know if that is the behavior you want

Comment: That's so awesome!! Exactly what I was looking for, for the first part of the question! Ah so excited ok! Is there any chance you can take a look at the second part if it's not too much trouble or anyone else? Would be awesome. Still playing around with it lol thanks so much for the first part though! I knew it was something small like that!

Comment: @Dimitrov I updated the answer. I'm not sure if that is what you are looking for but the spacing between the pictures is better with that.

Comment: That's actually perfect! I'll just do a full screen portfolio instead! So awesome. Thank you, just need to do a couple of adjustments and its perfect for what I need!